# Where do the bones of dead animals go?

Tags: zoology, ecology, palaeontology

I've spent quite a bit of time in the wild, but I've seen little to no bones lying on the ground.
Large bones such as skulls, spines, horns, hooves are not eaten by any other animals, and even microorganisms. thanks to which they can persist for decades on the ground surface. Especially in hot and dry climates, steppe and desert regions, as well as in the arctic.
Therefore, it should be expected that a large number of bones will be found on the surface of the soil, also underground in the topsoil.
But nothing like this actually happens.
Where do the bones of dead animals go?

Comment: Can't speak for all bones everywhere, but bones get eaten quite often. When I lived in the woods, I could see a carcass disappear bit by bit in a matter of days - far too quickly for disintegration - leaving only the hardest bones bare on the ground.

Comment: Same here, weeks later the remains would be visible only as glints of ivory through the overgrowth of ivy. After an autumn's leaf-fall, nothing the next year. Still there if you dig. I found a pig's lower jawbone, teeth and all thrown out of a rabit's burrow - decades old, not seen until the rabit found it in the way of its home-building efforts.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why don't we find animal corpses and skeletons all throughout the woods?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/73222/why-dont-we-find-animal-corpses-and-skeletons-all-throughout-the-woods)

Answer (score 3):

Even a superficial Google search will tell you by the title of the hits you get that bones are eaten, e.g. [my top hit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Osteophagy).

Osteophagy simply means *bone eating*. I'm not sure why it applies to herbivores in particular; maybe because it seems to be strange behavior in an herbivore, whereas it's expected in a carnivore.

Phosphate is crucial to life, but isn't abundant in 'edible nature' (plants, etc.). It is abundant in bone, however, and because it is crucial to growth and energy production, animals eat bones however they can. Some animals, e.g. those without teeth, will swallow small bones whole. Carnivores and capable omnivores will crush susceptible bones by chewing on them; herbivores will just grind away at them and consume the bits they can generate.

From Wikipedia, a cow chewing on a bone.

[image]

How about [a squirrel](https://www.bu.edu/articles/2016/squirrel-bone-gnawing/)?

[image]

Or a [deer eating human bones](https://www.nationalgeographic.com/animals/article/deer-eating-human-forensics-decomposition):

[image]

This answer could be longer, but why go on? The answer is obvious.

<sub>[Osteophagia: How Wild Animals Use Supplements](https://www.wildlifeact.com/blog/osteophagia-how-wild-animals-use-supplements/)</sub>

Comment: The O.hypothesis has the right to be, but I do not think that it is able to explain everything completely.
Let's start with O. is noted in a limited number of animal species, not in all.
It also follows from the context of the article that this is more a deviation variant due to adverse conditions than the norm.
An example would be  domestic animals that get along just fine without eating bones, because the food usually contains sufficient amounts of phosphate.
( more detail in  the next comment)

Comment: Another example, rabbits can eat the corpses of relatives.
But this happens only in conditions of critical hunger. Under normal circumstances, they never behave like this.
The situation is the same among people.

Herbivores cannot eat fresh bones, their digestive system is adapted for this.
We are clearly talking about heavily decomposed bones that have already lain for several years.
There are a few more interesting facts about this but I'm going to describe them in the following questions on the site.

Comment: @VladimirOrlov - It's not aberrant behavior, and it's not limited. True, if a diet is adequate in phosphorus, osteophagy decreases. But in nature, diets are not adequate in phosphorus. Carnivores prefer fresh bone, herbivores dried bone. Both want to eat bone. Mice and rats eat bone. One buzzard's diet is 70-90% bone. Mammal bite marks have been found on dinosaur bones. Something is not true because one prefers it to the truth. The "truth" is what is supported by the evidence. There is an adult rabbit corpse on my lawn. I love to observe nature, so have not removed it. ...

Comment: ...I found it because a buzzard was on my lawn. Three days ago, it was freshly dead and didn't smell so good. Today it has been reduced to fur and a few vertebral bones and a mandible. That is evidence to me that the bones do not just get covered up. I have only seen the buzzard at it, but am not watching it 24 hours/day. I suspect creatures have been eating it bit by bit.

Comment: the rabbit is a fairly small animal, so it is not so surprising that it was eaten.
  But there are much bigger animals and their bones.
in Tibet there are customs of sky burial, when the corpses are fed to the vultures.
but there the bones are specially crushed and even after that some of them remain lying on the ground.
​

Comment: @VladimirOrlov - Your point being?

Comment: this only happens to a small minority of bone. The first thing google kicks back is rarely the whole story.

Comment: @anongoodnurse I haven't any acceptable hypothesis. There's no reasonable explanation for this facts.

Comment: What about arm and leg bones, hips and skull, which only a hyena can chew on? And regions with high calcium content, like clay and limestone soils? Only about 50% of regions have calcium depleted water, soil and vegetation,  https://www.researchgate.net/figure/A-Map-of-calcium-hardness-as-calcium-carbonate-for-North-America-Note-that-calcium_fig2_236942539

Comment: @bandybabboon - Calcium isn't the problem; phosphorus is. Long bones get eaten (what bone do you think that bovine is eating?) The hardest bones break down eventually or not. The majority get eaten. And it's not only hyenas that are great at breaking bones.

Comment: @anongoodnurse, where i live there are just foxes and pigs, and only pigs can eat big bones, a horse femur is giant.

Comment: @bandybabboon - Which is it? First you said only hyenas could eat long bones, now you include pigs. What is the bull above eating, a dinosaur digit? Why don't you provide sources for your answer, instead of arguing with mine?

Comment: @anongoodnurse you're answer is great, The question specifically refers to large bones such as skulls, spines, horns, so I'm being logical. Skulls are huge bones and don't just fit in the leverage part of the jaw towards the molars, and horse femurs are pretty big too. I find a lot of skulls compared to other types of bones in the forests, so I think that osteophagy concerns stick-like bones. https://www.google.com/search?q=equus+femur&tbm=isch

Comment: @bandybabboon - Fair enough; I may have overread the question. I agree that the cranium is the most likely bone one will find in areas where animals live and die. Some vertebrae, but many get broken and eaten. I disagree with long bones; once in a while I'll  find a femoral head with the cartilage chewed off. For many years I had 28 acres, mostly wooded, with all kinds of carnivores and an abundance of deer. Yet on my walks through the woods, I never found long bones, vertebral bodies or antlers. I often found fur and feathers.

Answer (score 1):

### they rot, get eaten, or get weathered away. Under extremely rare circumstances they fossilize.

What you are talking about is called bone [taphonomy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taphonomy).

[image]

You can do a simple experiment yourself, put hooves or bones partially buried in dirt in your yard and check on them from time to time, depending on where oyu live what happens will vary quite a lot. Paleontologist and forensic scientists have studied this a lot to understand fossil and human remains respectively.

What happens to them

1. Normal erosion processes and soft tissue decomposition break the bone in to smaller pieces. The same thing that breaks down rocks breakdown bone just faster. Physical and chemical weather all work on bone. Bone is soft and permeable as rock goes so it weathers very quickly.
2. Bacteria, insects, fungi, plant roots, or other organisms break them down and eat them. You can prevent this by drying the bone out and keeping it away from soil, (soils keeps the bone moist and makes it easy for those things to reach the bone) Bone like any organic material rots, oxygen and water make it happen faster and bigger organisms can eat them faster.

You can see the same thing with any organic material which is why we dry meat and fruit to preserve them. Also why we cover organic materials like leather or wood in oils to keep them dry. or cover them in poisonous chemicals just like you can do with bone, it slows down their decomposition. in really dry places or conditions with no oxygen bone can take very long to decay. A cow skull defleshed and nailed to a barn in the desert will take a very long time to decay centuries or longer, a bone left on the jungle floor wet and covered in dirt and leaf litter will be gone in months, assuming you can keep things from eating it, (bone is a high demand resource in forests where phosphorous is in high demand).

Different materials decompose at different rates. Under absolutely perfect conditions the bone does not decay completely, creating a fossil. I personally have pulled unfossilized mammoth bones out of clay rich desert soil in Wyoming, the bone had all the structural strength of dry rotted wood, any handling caused bone to flake off, but it was still a complete mammoth leg bone, its decay had been severely slowed by dry, cold, anoxic conditions. We do find lots of buried bone in the right environments.

### Soils is not static

If you put bone on top of soil it will not stay on top of the soil. soils turns over due to thermal, erosional, and biological forces. things get buried, see frost heaving and soil creep as examples. Soil is not static it is always on the move. Deserts in particular tend to be highly erosional, which is why we look for fossil in deserts,  new rock is constantly being exposed and destroyed.

Now deserts and cold regions do have much slower rates of decay which is why you can find remains that are decades or even centuries old in such places. Bones are found in bogs and [permafrost for instance](https://www.smithsonianmag.com/science-nature/five-fascinating-ice-age-finds-discovered-in-yukon-permafrost-180979521/).  things like sunlight, temperature, abrasion, weather and such can all breakdown bone. Also you vastly overestimate how many animals there are in such places, even if all their bones did not decay they still would not make up a noticeable portion of the topsoil. in places where the animal remains are that common they do make up a significant portion of the soil we call those coral sand beaches, where mechanically broken up animal shells make up the majority of the soil.

**Sources about bone decomposition and diagenesis**

[https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/20646883/#:~:text=Abstract,or%20as%20long%20as%2030.](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/20646883/#:%7E:text=Abstract,or%20as%20long%20as%2030.)

https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/dust-to-dust/

https://digitalcommons.unl.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1061&context=nebanthro

https://www.jstor.org/stable/2400259

https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S003101821630164X

https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC8224596/

**Sources about soil and erosion turnover**

https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/agricultural-and-biological-sciences/soil-movement

https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/B9780123864734000014

**Bonus**

[Great simplified of review of decomposition.](https://www.scienceabc.com/humans/skeleton-mystery-dont-bones-decay-decompose.html)

Comment: Your first link is about **buried** bones: "The burial of remains below the surface has been found to effectively shut out many of the **most destructive decaying agents**, such as the natural elements and insect and **animal activity**. the other links are irrelevant, the third being only about soil, and do not support your answer (or the comment you left under my post.) I actually did the experiment you suggested inadvertently by leaving a dead rabbit where it was found. Three days later, almost all of the bones were gone. Supervoracious topsoil, maybe?

Comment: @anongoodnurse I added a few other sources for all manner of bone decomposition and diagenesis. I also ogranized them a bit more. I have done the experiment thousands of times to study early stages of fossilization. I never said osteophagy does not occur just that it is only one small part of a large variety of things that break down bone.

Answer (score 1):

Let's look at the [decomposition of a corpse](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corpse_decomposition) as a whole.

1. Fresh
2. Bloat
3. Active decay
4. Advanced decay
5. Dry state

You can skip to the dry state, which answers your question specifically.

---

A prerequisite to studying decomposition is knowing that decomposers break down organic material by secreting enzymes turning it into dark liquid form that's possible for them to absorb. Foul gases are produced in the process.

Also, it's best to think about decomposition as a bunch of processes caused by several agents happening and progressing at the same time.

---

When you hear fresh state, think of anything that ends with mortis:

- Algor mortis (decrease of body temperature to ambient temperature)
- Rigor mortis (temporary stiffness of muscles due to decreased ATP which is required to relax muscles until decay starts)
- Livor mortis (pooling of blood at the site closest to the ground)

---

Bloat happens because gut flora starts breaking through the wall of the gut. The wall is normally protected by the epithelial cell layer which has a high rate of shedding and regeneration. Since regeneration stops, flora can now bypass into the underlying tissue and start feeding on the body from the inside which results in the formation of

- Gas (has foul smell)
- Liquid (dark purge fluid that leaks through orifices because of increased pressure from gases in the intestine)

[Autolysis](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autolysis_(biology)) also starts where lysosomes containing lysozymes break up and release the hydrolytic enzymes which break down tissue so skin slippage may occur.

---

Liquifaction by decomposers continues causing darkening and loosening of the exterior.

Blowflies are attracted to the foul smells (even the smell of excrement) and thus, approach the corpse early and lay their eggs which hatch releasing maggots that feed on the corpse.

Several species of insects also start feeding on the corpse but that starts later.

Adipocere (corpse wax) may also form from decomposition of fat preventing further decomposition.

---

In advanced decay, most tissue has [liquified and loosened](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Putrefaction).

---

What remains from the corpse is the dry or skeletonised state. Dry here indicates that all the liquid produced from the action of decomposers has been taken up and what remains is the hard tissue, bone or the skeleton.

---

If the skeleton becomes covered in soil, scavengers (animals) do not [eat](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Osteophagy#:%7E:text=It%20has%20been%20seen%20in,to%20chew%20softer%20fresh%20bones.) it and it breaks down in acidic soil over a long time period.

If the soil is neutral, it takes much longer time for this to take place.

If the soil is

- dry, anoxic or slightly alkaline (unsuitable for decomposer activity)
- salty (has [minerals](https://simple.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mohs_scale_of_mineral_hardness#:%7E:text=Gypsum%20is%20harder%3A%20it%20can,scale%20is%20for%20natural%20minerals.) which can form long-lasting hard structures)

the bones may [fossilize](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fossil).

Answer (score -1):

When you study archaeology, you dig and find everything becomes buried very fast through burrowing and overgrowth subsidence. You can find *a lot* of bones when you walk a minute away from the beaten track, and very rarely on paths, often gray and beige. Humans very often move nice skulls as trophies.

Skulls provide a microclimate for moss, ants, beetles, plants, low-wind zones and snags to collect leaves. Humans like to pick them up and move them, rodents gnaw them, the jaw tumbles away, bug and bird droppings, acids and humidity dissolve them, frost cracks the pores.

Plants compete for space and grow around bones and hide them. Bugs dig networks of burrows and make the soil cave in a bit, worms place middens on the sides, A hoof or a femur will be covered by wild grass in 3-5 years, a horse skull in 10-20 years.

In the arctic there aren't horses, cows, deer, only seashore megafauna. Bones get snowed over. Else they are subject to freeze-thaw weathering, water stays in the pores of the bones, freezes and expands every day, and erodes them.

In the forest, leaf fall and sticks accumulate 1-5cm every year, trees fall over, the soil is alive with fungus mycelia and bugs, It's also quite an acid environment. Bones would be expected to stay uncovered for less than 15-20 years.

In the desert, there aren't lots of big animals, and the bones can last a very long time there, we can find awesome cadavers in regions of low biological, geological and glacial activity.

Human transportation near paths
Scavenging
Animals hide away when they are ill
Gnawing
Moss
Freeze thaw
Geological activity
Subsidence
Glacial activity
Sand dunes
Trampling by other animals

Comment: I'm not sure what's going on with the last paragraph. Also, -1 for not mentioning osteophagy. If this answer were all there was to the fate of bones, we'd be buried in bones, which is clearly not the case.